# Can I thaw frozen spinach that´s meant to be boiled frozen?

Tags: boiling, frozen, spinach

The frozen spinach package says to boil while frozen, but I never seem to manage to get it cooked the way I like it. Either the center stays frozen (the package says 3-5min with boiling water and I need to keep it over 10min), or a big percentage of the spinach is way too bland.

I thought maybe thawing before, and then boiling, or even cooking in the pan would solve this. I don´t use fresh spinach primarily because of the money and convenience.

Can anyone tell me if this is a good idea?

Comment: Have you tried buying brands of spinach which sell it not in one large frozen brick, but as separate balls? They thaw nicer in the pan.

Comment: @rumtscho they don't sell those in the shops I usually visit.. I'll try to look for them tho, it looks like a great solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my experience frozen spinach will never be close to fresh, so I guess it depends on what sort of consistency you are hoping to get. In any case boiling from frozen sounds like the world's worst way to prepare it! There is no reason you can't thaw it before you cook it, but I wouldn't boil it in any case. I'd that it and drain it well, maybe even squeezing excess water out of it before pan frying it. Season it well with salt and pepper, a bit of butter never hurts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm going to try your suggestion of squeezing the water and pan frying. Will update you on the outcome :)

Comment: So I just tried it, and it did end up way better. It was also very convenient to clean as I cooked it in the pan with some garlic. Accepting your answer!